# Kcachegrind/callgrind is inaccurate for dispatcher functions?

Tags: valgrind, call-graph, kcachegrind, callgrind

I have a model code on which kcachegrind/callgrind reports strange results. It is kind of dispatcher function. The dispatcher is called from 4 places; each call says, which actual `do_J` function to run (so the `first2` will call only `do_1` and `do_2` and so on)

Source (this is a model of actual code)

```
#define N 1000000

int a[N];
int do_1(int *a) { int i; for(i=0;i<N/4;i++) a[i]+=1; }
int do_2(int *a) { int i; for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) a[i]+=2; }
int do_3(int *a) { int i; for(i=0;i<N*3/4;i++) a[i]+=3; }
int do_4(int *a) { int i; for(i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]+=4; }

int dispatcher(int *a, int j) {
    if(j==1) do_1(a);
    else if(j==2) do_2(a);
    else if(j==3) do_3(a);
    else do_4(a);
}

int first2(int *a) { dispatcher(a,1); dispatcher(a,2); }
int last2(int *a) { dispatcher(a,4); dispatcher(a,3); }
int inner2(int *a) { dispatcher(a,2); dispatcher(a,3); }
int outer2(int *a) { dispatcher(a,1); dispatcher(a,4); }

int main(){
    first2(a);
    last2(a);
    inner2(a);
    outer2(a);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -O0`; Callgrinded with `valgrind --tool=callgrind`; kcachegrinded with `kcachegrind` and `qcachegrind-0.7`.

Here is a full callgraph of the application. All paths to do_J go through dispatcher and this is good (the do_1 is just hided as too fast, but it is here really, just left to do_2)

[image: Full]

Lets focus on `do_1` and check, who called it (this picture is incorrect):

[image]

And this is very strange, I think, only `first2` and `outer2` called `do_1` but not all.

Is it a limitation of callgrind/kcachegrind? How can I get accurate callgraph with weights (proportional to running time of every function, with and without its childs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is limitation of callgrind format. It doesn't store full trace; it only stores parent-child calls information.

There is a google-perftools project with pprof/libprofiler.so CPU profiler, http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html . `libprofiler.so` can get profile with calltraces and it will store every trace event with full backtrace. `pprof` is converter of libprofile's output to graphic formats or to callgrind format. In full view the result will be the same as in kcachegrind; but if you will focus on some function, e.g. do_1 using pprof's option focus; it will show accurate calltree when focused on function.

Comment: There is similar  test with same problem described here: [http://www.yosefk.com/blog/how-profilers-lie-the-cases-of-gprof-and-kcachegrind.html](http://www.yosefk.com/blog/how-profilers-lie-the-cases-of-gprof-and-kcachegrind.html) "Here's what we'll see: ...  this information is not enough to know what the call tree needs knowing to show the truth." And there is workaround - the `--separate-callers=N` option of callgrind to record N slots of callstack

Comment: Valgrind documentation has useful option `--separate-callers=N`, [documented for callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.cycles (6.2.4. Avoiding cycles) and http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.options.separation (6.3.4. Cost entity separation options)